# Having multiple correct answers in a user defined dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm writing a review quiz for a pharmacology class. I switched styles based on feedback I received to a different question but have encountered a problem. I want to have multiple correct answers as the user may enter the answer slightly differently.
The previous format I was using would have looked something like this:

```
   x = "What is the starting dose for oral Enalipril in HTN?"
   ques1 = enterbox(msg = x, title = version)
   if ques1.lower() in ["2.5-5", "2.5-5mg","2.5mg"]:
        add() 
        #which is a function I had described above to track points and display that the answer was correct
        ques2()
   elif ques1.lower() in ["skip"]:
        skip()
        que2()
   else:
        loss()
        que1()
```

"Skip" and "Loss" are just basic functions to keep track of skipped and wrong inputs.

Now the new format I'm trying to use is:

```
from easygui import enterbox

question_answer_pairs = [
    ("What Class of medication is Enalapril?", "ACE Inhibitor"),
    ("What is the starting oral dose of Enalapril for HTN?", ["2.5-5mg", "2.5-5","2.5mg"]),
    ("which type of metabolism provides the maximum amount of ATP needed for contraction?", "aerobic")
]

VERSION = 'Pharmacology Prep Exam'

class ResultStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_correct = 0
        self.num_skipped = 0
        self.num_wrong = 0

    def show_results(self):
        print("Results:")
        print("  Correct:", self.num_correct)
        print("  Skipped:", self.num_skipped)
        print("  Wrong:  ", self.num_wrong)


def ask_question(q, a, rs, retry_on_fail=True):
    while True:
        resp = enterbox(msg=q, title=VERSION)
        # Force resp to be a string if nothing is entered (so .lower() doesn't throw)
        if resp is None: resp = ''
        if resp.lower() == a.lower():
            rs.num_correct += 1
            return True
        if resp.lower() == "skip":
            rs.num_skipped += 1
            return None

          # If we get here, we haven't returned (so the answer was neither correct nor
        #   "skip").  Increment num_wrong and check whether we should repeat.
        rs.num_wrong += 1
        if retry_on_fail is False:
            return False

# Create a ResultsStore object to keep track of how we did
store = ResultStore()

# Ask questions
for (q,a) in question_answer_pairs:
    ask_question(q, a, store)

# Display results (calling the .show_results() method on the ResultsStore object)
store.show_results()
```

(The above code is almost taken verbatim from a different user that responded to a different question, it works but I take no credit for writing it) 
 OK, hopefully that copied and pasted correctly, but it functions fine for the first question but crashes on the second one, returning:

```
  File "./APPrac.py", line 7, in <module>
    ("which type of metabolism provides the maximum amount of ATP needed for contraction?", "aerobic")
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I tried getting rid of the brackets and throwing in "or" between the answers but got the same error.
I'm pretty much shooting in the dark at this point because I'm not even entirely sure how to search for help.

I'm completely self taught so all the Barney level explanations provided mean the world to me. 
Thanks

EDIT: So placing the comma in line 6 corrected the problem. But I get the following error now

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./dict.py", line 47, in <module>
     ask_question(q, a, store)
  File "./dict.py", line 29, in ask_question
     if resp.lower() == a.lower():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

It goes away if I remove the question with multiple answers though.

Comment: Please include the complete exception traceback in the question. I don't have easygui installed, but I might be able to figure out the error if I could see *where* it happens. Also, your code is not a [mcve] - you never do anything with the `ResultStore` object after you create it.

Comment: Alright, I edited to show the exact output when I try to run it and included the last few lines so the entire program is in the example now.

Comment: You're passing `["2.5-5mg", "2.5-5","2.5mg"]` as `a`, which you are then trying to `.lower()` which doesn't make any sense. Have consistent types in your list of tuples (i.e. make *every* second element a string or *every* second element a list). *Especially* if you're iterating over them!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma, so instead of having a list like `[(...), (a, b), (c, d)]` you actually have a list that looks like `[(...), (a, b)(c, d)]` where it thinks your calling the second object `(a, b)` with the arguments `(c, d)`.

Change

```
question_answer_pairs = [
    ("What Class of medication is Enalapril?", "ACE Inhibitor"),
    ("What is the starting oral dose of Enalapril for HTN?", ["2.5-5mg", "2.5-5","2.5mg"])
    ("which type of metabolism provides the maximum amount of ATP needed for contraction?", "aerobic")
]
```

to

```
question_answer_pairs = [
    ("What Class of medication is Enalapril?", "ACE Inhibitor"),
    ("What is the starting oral dose of Enalapril for HTN?", ["2.5-5mg", "2.5-5","2.5mg"]),  # <-- this comma was missing
    ("which type of metabolism provides the maximum amount of ATP needed for contraction?", "aerobic")
]
```

---

Comment: Thank you, I spent a crazy amount of time rearranging and changing everything else and missed that.

Comment: To save time in future, look more closely at your error message it says `line 7, tuple object not callable`. So it thinks the tuple on line 7 is being called at that point.

Comment: Alright I edited the original post to reflect the new error I'm getting